# Unable to import databinding class in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am unable to import the **databinding** class.

Here's my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test1"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }

    }

      .......
```

And here's my MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.test1

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.test1.databinding // <-- Shows ERROR in this line

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

here's my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

I have synced the Gradle, I have also tried restarting Android Studio, but it simply won't work.

What should I do??

Comment: What do you want to do with that import? If it simply doesn't work then **rebuild project** and check again.

Comment: Okay, @JeelVankhede **rebuilding the project** worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change binding position:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test1"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to see your XML file

Comment: I've uploaded the xml file, please have a look at it.

Comment: Now **Clear**  and  **Rebuild**  your project